# Cannot install Ckmeans package on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: r, ubuntu

I am not able to install Rcpp and many other packages (e.g. devtools) as a requirement for the opm-package.

Ubuntu 18.04, R Version: 3.5.1, gcc version 7.3.0

Can anybody give suggestions to fix this issue?

EDIT: I managed now to install rcpp via apt-get; I used the below suggested repos and R 3.5.1. Now I am stuck with installing Ckmeans (Package maintainer contacted).

EDIT_2: The author sent me a new version of Ckmeans, but the problem persists. To sum up: unable to install ckmeans; Ubuntu 18.04, R 3.5.1, repos c2d4u3.5, cran repos.

Comment: Do you have `r-base-dev` installed? Have you considered using `r-cran-rcpp` from https://launchpad.net/~marutter/+archive/ubuntu/c2d4u3.5?

Comment: "Impossible". I just prepared another release, on the same platform.  You may have something weird in your `~/.R/Makevars` or some other local change.  The fact that you quote `Install.packages()` does not install confidence as the function is lower-cased...

Comment: And Ralf is of course correct:  If compiling is too hard or otherwise encumbered, _use the existing binaries_,  There is a reason we work hard to provide them.

Comment: Maybe uninstall the `opm` package, restore settings and try without.  This works "everywhere else" including CRAN, Travis, Debian, Ubuntu, ... for a decent-sized number of users.

Comment: Thank you for all the answers. Yes, I installed r-base-dev. I couldn't install r-cran-rcpp (tried), same issue. I don't have a ~/.R directory. It is install.packages (i accidently deleted I during copy paste). I also deleted all the libraries. I was not aware of the option of installing packages as binaries under linux?

Comment: ...and on a fedora machine (f28) i was able to install opm, so I guess something's wrong with my ubuntu-install.

Comment: Debian (and therefore also Ubuntu) contains a fair number of R package, c.f. https://packages.debian.org/sid/gnu-r/. These are designed to work with the R version from the distribution. You are using a more recent version of R. I assume that comes from CRAN. If that is the case, then you can enable the c2d4u3.5 repository, c.f. link above or https://rubuntu.netlify.com/post/2018-05-25-announcing-c2d4u3-5/, and install `r-cran-rcpp` **from there**. The version from the default Ubuntu repository will not work! If you get an error with that, then please [edit] your post to include it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After today's System-update I was able to install Ckmeans.1d.dp_4.2.2 and opm_1.3.72 without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

update: I removed the R-bionic ppa and reinstalled R (3.5.0) with r-base-dev. I managed to tackle down nearly all the dependencies for opm, if not within R, so at least with the ubuntu-r-cran-packages (from the abovely mentioned repos); only one dependency is missing (OPM-Script): Ckmeans. I tried to install from source with 5 different versions, but so far without success.

Comment: This is mostly just pilot error. I recommend you delete the question,

Comment: Also, the compilation error you show is different from the 'mixing R 3.4.* and R 3.5.*' which you only get at package load, and _not_ from `gcc` /  `g++`.